# adding and calling company names in routes mvc

Tags: asp.net-mvc, model-view-controller, routes, asp.net-mvc-routing

I am implementing the way discussed in the following thread:
[Adding company name in Routes mvc 4](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28812432/adding-company-name-in-routes-mvc-4/32472804#32472804)

```
 routes.MapRoute(
                name: "Default",
                url: "{CompanyName}/{controller}/{action}/{id}",
                defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional },
                constraints: new { CompanyName = "Company1|Company2|Company3" }
            );
```

but how to call this i.e. `Company2/Home/Index` from code on another action ?

Currently, I am using `return RedirectToAction("Index", "Home")` but want to add `Company2` in it and redirect dynamically.

Comment: `return RedirectToAction("Index", "Home", new { CompanyName = "Company2" });`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You just need to add `CompanyName` to the route values.

```
return RedirectToAction("Index", "Home", new { CompanyName = "Company2" });
```